# Change color of even row in the list for all pages SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, wiki-pages

I add JavaScript to a wiki page which has a web-part of list. I want all even rows in the list display background color in green. There are 10 pages in this web-part. But the script just works for the first page.

How can I change color for all pages?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){


$("tr:even").css("background-color", "green");});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @AmalHashim Thank you!!!    I change the script, I use CSS directly.       '#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-alternating
    {
        background-color: Tan;
    }
</style>'

Comment: @AmalHashim your photo is good !

Comment: Thanks MKQian. If you can post your solution as an answer it might help the community.

Answer (score 2):

I change the script, I use CSS directly. It works well

```
<style>
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-alternating 
{ background-color:  green; } 
</style>
```